# Progress image between asp.net pages not coming on android browser

Tags: jquery, android, asp.net

I want to show a progress image between two pages precisely on button click.I have a javascript function which I am calling on button click.But the progress image is not showing for all the pages.On analysis I found the function is getting called but still no image is being shown.The following works absolutely fine for Iphone browser.

```
function ShowProcessingImage()
{
try{
        var divProcessingImageY = $(document).height();
        var processingImageY = $(window).scrollTop() + ($(window).height()/2) - 45;
        var processingImageX = (($(window).width()/2) - 45);            


        $('body').append('<div id="divProcessingImage" style="position:absolute;width:100%; height:'+divProcessingImageY+'px; top:0; left:0; background-color:#7f7f7f; text-align:center; vertical-align:middle; z-index:98;opacity:.7"></div>');
        $('#imgProcessing').css({'z-index' : 99, 'top' : processingImageY + 'px', 'left' : processingImageX + 'px'});
        $('#imgProcessing').show(); \\imgProcessing is a div block in my master page.           


    }
catch (err) {
}
```

}

Comment: "But the progress image is not showing for all the pages." - means for some pages it shown? also post some code how you load the webpages in android?

Comment: I have the following div block in my master page.All the pages do reference this master page.                                                     <div id="imgProcessing" style="display:none;position:absolute;top:0;left:0;z-index:-1; font-size:20px; font-weight:bold; color:White"><img src="../MobileOrderingImages/ajax-loader.gif" style="padding-left:25px;" height="24px" width="24px"/><br />Loading...</div>